# Ngrok not tunneling properly Nginx

Tags: nginx, ip, ngrok, tunnel

I have my flask application deployed on Nginx over my VM.

Everything is deployed Ok and I can request my apis on http://my.ip.number (I have a public IP)

But when I run **Ngrok** (I need https and I don't have a domain name to generate a SSL certificate), the URL https//number.ngrok.io **shows me the Nginx home page (Welcome to Nginx) instead my webapp**.

Why is this happening?

P.D: When I run "curl localhost" I get the Nginx Welcome Page but when I exec "curl -4 localhost" I get my webapp home page

**etc/nginx/site-available/myproject**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/datascience/chatbot-cima/chatbot.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/datascience/chatbot-cima/chatbot.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/datascience/chatbot-cima/chatbot.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name public.ip;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/datascience/chatbot-cima/chatbot.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any request coming in from ngrok, has the `Host` header set to the ngrok URL.  The behaviour of nginx would be to try and match one of the `server` blocks in your configuration above, and default to the first one if no `server_name` matches the `Host` header.

However, I'm guessing there's another configuration file at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/0-default` which has a `listen` directive with `default_server` set.  That will be catching these requests and serving the "Welcome to nginx!" page.

I suggest you look for that file, and remove it which should solve the issue.

However you could also simplify the above configuration and simply have:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/datascience/chatbot-cima/chatbot.sock;
    }
}
```

Provided there's not another `server` block hiding somewhere else in the configuration with a directive like `listen 80 default_server;` then this should catch all requests.

For more info see: [How nginx processes a request](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)